# I can't upload a markdown file by the CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I don't know how to set the `allowed_types`, and the markdown file suffix is `.md`. It always says:

```
The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.
```

English is not my native language, so I hope this makes sense. My code:

```
public function do_upload()
{
  $config['upload_path']      = './blog/';
  $config['allowed_types']    = '';      //file's tye
  $config['max_size']     = 50;     
  $config['max_width']        = 1024;
  $config['max_height']       = 768;
  $this->load->library('upload', $config);

  if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
  {
    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

    $this->load->view('houtai_view', $error);
  }
  else
  {
    $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

    //$this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to `allowed_types` in your `$config` array

```
$config['allowed_types'] = 'md';
```

If you want to allow all kinds of files than you can use `*` like:

```
$config['allowed_types'] = '*';
```

[File Uploading Class](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html)

Comment: @j-cai than accept the answer this will help to other click on left tick

Answer (score 0):

**Customize  File type  allow **

```
$config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can edit `APPATH.'config/mimes.php'` file and add `'md'   =>    'text/plain',` to array.